# Is it possible to keep an iOS app running for ever listening to location update and enabling Maps Car Routing?

Tags: ios, background

How does app like Google Maps keep running in the background, the app is not killed but it runs forever.. how does that work?

Answer (score 0):

1.You can go to .plist  and add one item as "Application does not run in background",then set this to "NO"

2.Add one item as "Required background modes" ,set it with you use type

it is my method,i hope that can help you :)